# Require.config throws error: EXPECTING 'STRING' in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this `require.config` setup:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: '../common/vendor/angular/angular'
    },

    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

require(['angular'], function (ng) {


});
```

When the script is loaded, it throws this error:

[image: script error]

Does anyone know what this is? It is hindering `angular` to load.

This is how I load the script:

```
<script src="common/vendor/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/main.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
Seems like adding this:

```
require(['angular'], function (ng) {
    ng.bootstrap(document.documentElement);
});
```

loads angular correctly. Still throws the error though.

Comment: try retyping it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is from the `JSONView` extension. Turn off the extension will eliminate the error. But that's not a error at all. It has nothing to do with the real app/script.